# Finding the index of a string with specific requirements?

Tags: java, substring, processing, indexof

I'm a bit of a newbie to programming. :P

I'm working with Processing right now to create a table of subjects with their ID, Title and Availability.

I have a 2D array that contains information like this:

```
units[0][0] = "CAKE100"; //Subject ID
units[1][0] = "Eating Cake And Baking Too"; //Subject Title
units[2][0] = "November"; //Subject Availability

units[0][1] = "TACO204"; //Subject ID
units[1][1] = "Tacos And Other Delicious Things"; //Subject Title
units[2][1] = "April"; //Subject Availability

units[0][2] = "KITC102"; //Subject ID
units[1][2] = "Kitchen Safety"; //Subject Title
units[2][2] = "June"; //Subject Availability
```

I'm trying to filter through the unit[0][x] section to find the index location of every Subject ID that has "1" in the fourth position of the string.

For example, I want to return [0] [0] and [0] [2], because "CAKE100" and "KITC102" both have "1" in the fourth position.

I've tried to use indexOf or .substring but for some reason I can't figure it out.

EDIT:
Not sure how much help it will be but here's my butchered code:

```
    void checkLevel100() {
for ( int j = 0; j < units.length; j++) {
    position = 0; 
   // position = units[0][j].indexOf("1"); //This returns 4;
    if (units[0][j].substring(4) == "1") { //This doesn't run at all, and so it returns 0.
      position = j;
    }
    fill(0);
    text(position, width/2, height/2);
  }
}
```

I also did what Kevin Workman suggested. Here is the code for that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
    if(units[0][i] == "TACO204"){ //This results in 1, as expected
      location[i] = i;
    println(i);
    }
```

Once again, thank you for your time :)

Comment: Please post the code which you tried, so that it is easy to fix it.

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: @VatsalSura 
Sorry, posted it now. :)

Comment: You've posted your code, but you haven't told us exactly what you're confused about. Which of the steps in my answer are you stuck on? You might want to post a new question with an updated [mcve] along with a more specific question- if you're only asking about the `if` statement, then you don't need to ask about the arrays. If you're only asking about the arrays, then you don't need to ask about the `if` statement. Try to isolate your problem into smaller individual problems, and then ask about those one at a time.

Comment: @KevinWorkman
My loops seem to work fine on their own, it's just when .substring or IndexOf come into play where it seems to stop working.
So I presume I'm using them wrong or something?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] along with a specific question? What exactly do you mean when you say it stops working? What happens instead? You need to be very specific when describing programming problems, otherwise it's hard to help you. Btw, **don't use == when comparing `String` values.** Use the `equals()` function instead. `units[0][i] == "TACO204"` needs to be `units[0][i].equals("TACO204")` - google "Java String equals" for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break your problem down into smaller steps.

**Step 1:** Loop over your 2D array. You might use a nested `for` loop for this.

To test that this step works, you might just print every element in your 2d array before worrying about any logic.

**Step 2:** Write an `if` statement that checks whether the value at that index passes your test.

To test that this step works, you might want to create a separate program that just tests a hardcoded value instead of using arrays.

**Step 3:** Once you have the first two steps working, then you can save the indexes that pass your test into some kind of data structure. You might us an `ArrayList<Integer>` for this.

Create a separate example program that just loops over an array without worrying about any logic. Create another separate program that just uses an `if` statement to test your condition against a hard-coded value. Then if you get stuck on a specific step, you can post a more specific question along with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be simpler for you to store your subject's values as an object of a [class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm).  Perhaps store the numerical portion of the ID as an int too?  Using a class will enable you to write more human readable code.

```
public class FoodSubject {
    String stringID;
    int numID;
    String title;
    String availability;

    public FoodSubject(String stringID, int numID,
                   String title, String availability) {

        this.stringID = stringID;
        this.numID = numID;
        this.title = title;
        this.availability = availability;
    }
}
```

To make a new array of your FoodSubject objects use this code:

```
FoodSubject[] subjectArray = new FoodSubject[3];
subjectArray[0] = new FoodSubject("CAKE", 100, "Eating Cake And Baking Too", "November");
```

Access the values like this `subjectArray[0].numID`

Look into overriding the toString() method in your class to print out all the values of your subject easily.  This will help you identify problems in the rest of your code much easier!

If you still want to store the entire ID as a String use the [charAt(int index)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm) function to test if the character is a '1'.

This `if (units[0][j].substring(4) == "1") {` code is incorrect.  Look at the String Java documentation for information on what substring does.